# Prevent popup from appearing when clicking outside WMS layer

Tags: geoserver, openlayers-2, wms, popup, getfeatureinfo

I am projecting a WMS layer on a map using OpenLayers and Geoserver. The next thing I want to do is to display info on any given feature in my WMS-layer in a pop up whenever a user clicks it.

This is all working fine, but my problem is that whenever I click outside the WMS layer, I get an empty pop up. However, I only want a pop up to appear when a user clicks an actual feature.

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Code:

```
info = new OpenLayers.Control.WMSGetFeatureInfo({
    url: 'http://../geoserver/cite/wms', title: 'Vraag informatie op over een melding door erop te klikken',
    queryVisible: true,
    eventListeners: {
    getfeatureinfo: function(event) {
        deletePopup();
        popup = new OpenLayers.Popup.FramedCloud( "chicken", map.getLonLatFromPixel(event.xy), null, event.text, null, true );
        map.addPopup(popup); } } });
map.addControl(info); info.activate();
```

Comment: can you share your code to see what is wrong with it?

Comment: info = new OpenLayers.Control.WMSGetFeatureInfo({
  url: 'http://../geoserver/cite/wms',
  
  title: 'Vraag informatie op over een melding door erop te klikken',
   queryVisible: true,
  eventListeners: {
   getfeatureinfo: function(event) {
    deletePopup();
    popup = new OpenLayers.Popup.FramedCloud(
      "chicken",
      map.getLonLatFromPixel(event.xy),
      null,
      event.text,
         null,
     true
    );
    map.addPopup(popup);
   }
  }
 });
 map.addControl(info);
 info.activate();

Answer (score 1):

fixed it already!

I added this to my code (the stuff in bold):

...event) {deletePopup(); **if (event.text.indexOf("") != -1) {**
popup = new OpenLayers...

(And an extra } after map.addPopup(popup); obviously.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe is more intuitive to ask:

> if (event.features.length != 0)

If you don't touch a feature, OpenLayers will set this parameter to 0, because the GeoServer response is "empty".